# Bootstrap datepicker issue with chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, date, razorengine

This is my HTML

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control form-inline "} })
    <span style="background-color:lightgray" class="form-control-feedback"><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-2x"></i></span>
```

This my jquery code-

```
$("#Date").datepicker({
     autoclose: true,
     todayHighlight: true
});
```

following code works in Firefox and IE but does not work in chrome.

Error in chrome

> jquery-1.12.4.js:8254 The specified value "12/07/2016" does not
>   conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".

if i add `format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'` in JavaScript code 
then after selecting date, chrome doesn't show expected format.

Date format in Chrome : mm/dd/yyyy.

Date format in Firefox : yyyy-mm-dd.

I'm not able to find the solution. 
I want date format in all browser : mm/dd/yyyy

Answer (score 0):

In your js code explicitly mention the desired format:

```
$("#Date").datepicker({
     autoclose: true,
     todayHighlight: true,
     dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
});
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

UPDATE:

If this didn't help you can always hook into onselect method of datepicker and format your date however you want:

```
$('#Date').datepicker( {
    onSelect: function(date) {
        alert(date);
    },
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
});
```